# Is there a selenium driver for Microsoft's Edgium?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

I believe that the title says it all. I am really tired of having multiple browsers , which have the exact same job with a different name. And I don't want to have too many bloatware , just for the sake of developing Ruby apps. Since I am a beginner , I wont be bothered by any incompatibility with Firefox or some other browser.
So , is the Edgium driver available?
Or is it that the chromium drivers work with them too?

Answer (score 0):

There is support for chrome based edge in selenium-webdriver 4.x which is currently in alpha release. Also the current version of `webdrivers` will pull the actual driver binary needed on your platform.

Comment: What is the name of the driver for edgium ? I know for Firefox , it is selenium_driver , and for chrome , it is selenium_chrome_driver. Any ideas ?

Comment: @AshvithShetty I think you're confused about what you're asking for - the binary driver for firefox is called `geckodriver` for chrome it's called `chromedriver` and for edge its `edgedriver` - If you're asking what you need to do to register that with Capybara then your question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872618/new-microsoft-edge-and-selenium-web-driver

Answer (score 0):

By *Microsoft's Edgium* if you meant '[new Microsoft Edge Browser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge)' > yes, the selenium web-drivers are available in the official page.

For each browser version, the respective selenium web-drivers are available [in this 'WebDriver for MIcrosoft's new Edge' page](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I will check the latest Selenium. Are they , by any means , available for ruby gem testing with Capybara?